# Print out same format with escape characters in HTML from JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angular-ui

I'm having a problem with printing out JSON data in HTML

```
var a = "We are the world.\n \tWelcome to our place.";
```

let's assume that I have this json data from the backend and I wanna print out something like this.

```
<div>
We are the world.
  Welcome to our place.
</div>
```

I've tried with ng-bind-html but it shows all string inline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it simply. Because **\n** and **\t** are not recognized encoding for Html. You have to replace it with the recognized Html encoding first. You can do this by the following way:

```
$scope.a = "We are the world.\n \tWelcome to our place."
$scope.a.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

But now if you bind this text into Html it will omit the extra spaces before the word **Welcome** and leave only one space.

So, to solve this problem you have to bind this Html inside a **pre** tag. It will preserve your formatting.

```
<pre>{{a}}<pre>
```

I have added a demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2twWjmWPCKGxcrh7QEgf?p=preview

Comment: this can solve the issue with \n but not \t. I'm ok with omitting spaces before the world **Welcome** but keep the track of \t. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickBlind It will take care of both \n and \t. I have added a demo. You can see there.

Answer (score 0):

You can let tell browser to keep your white spaces by using `style="white-space: pre"`

If you still need the auto wrapping, you can use `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: sorry, what I need is not auto-wrapping but keeping the styles from JSON in HTML. Thanks.